# Recognizing whether a graph is a k-tree

Tags: graphs

The $k$-vertex complete graph, $K_k$, is a $k$-tree. A *$k$-tree* with $n+1$ vertices $(n \geq k)$ is constructed from a $k$-tree on $n$ vertices by adding a vertex adjacent to all vertices of one of its $K_k$ subgraphs, and only to those vertices.

Is there an algorithm to recognize whether a graph is a k-tree? What is its time complexity? Are there efficient algorithms for special cases, particularly for k = 2, 3, 4, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two facts:

- The $k$-trees are exactly the chordal graphs where every maximal clique has $k+1$ vertices and every minimal separator has $k$ vertices (or it's $K_k$ or $K_{k+1}$)
- In chordal graphs, the maximal cliques and the minimal separators can be enumerated in linear time (see e.g. [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019011000536))

In conclusion, there is a linear time algorithm for recognizing $k$-trees, for any $k$.

Comment: Good! By the way, it is possible to recognize chordal graphs in linear time.